# Toggle active class in nav bar with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<ul>
                <li id="tabHome" class="active"><a href="@Href("~")">Home</a></li>
                <li id="tabCMDS"  ><a href="@Href("~/CMDS")">CMDS</a></li>
                <li id="tabServiceMonitor" ><a href="@Href("~/Monitor")">Service Monitor</a></li>
                <li id="tabBatchInterface" ><a href="@Href("~/BatchInterface")">Batch Interface</a></li>
            </ul>
```

So I wanted to bind to `click` of each of these Id's, and set `class="active"` on the one that was clicked, and remove it from all others.

I can do the first part, but how can I do the latter?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
$(function() {
   $("li").click(function() {
      // remove classes from all
      $("li").removeClass("active");
      // add class to the one we clicked
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

It would be wise to give meaningful classes to the `<li>`'s so you can properly select just those, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 11):

No need to bind a click event to each ID but instead bind to all of the list items of this unordered list.  Then use the .parent().children() methods.  Following should work:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).parent().children('li').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: 7 years later comment, but : `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably find this better (otherwise the page will jump) -

```
$(function() {
$("li").click(function() {
  // remove classes from all
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  // add class to the one we clicked
  $(this).addClass("active");
  // stop the page from jumping to the top
  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: If you want to prevent the page from jumping, you should simply call preventDefault() on the event. Returning false can have unintended side effects such as preventing future event propagation.

`$("li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active') ;

    });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/UVyKe/1/

Comment: 7 years later comment, but : `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')`

Answer (score 0):

Give the ul an id or class, and select off of it.

```
<ul id = "nav">...

var $navItems = $('#nav > li');
$navItems.click(function(){
    $navItems.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li").click(function()
{
$("ul .active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add active class using below single line without using any event

```
$('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
```

[link to refer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/)