# Needs to toggle 'active' class when navigation list items are selected

Tags: jquery

I am using twitter bootstrap and trying to set 'active' class to the navigation list item by using jquery when a list item is selected.

Below is my code

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
              <li id="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li id="gadget"><a href="/category/gadgets"><span>Gadgets + Geeky</span></a></li>
              <li id="toys"><a href="/category/toys"><span>Toys</span></a></li>
              <li id="wearables"><a href="/category/wearables"><span>Wearables</span></a></li>
              <li id="home_office"><a href="/category/home-office"><span>Home + Office</span></a></li>
              <li id="food_drinks"><a href="/category/food-drinks"><span>Food + Drinks</span></a></li>
              <li id="kids"><a href="/category/kids"><span>Kids Stuff</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <script>
              $( document ).ready(function() {
                 $('ul li').click(function() {
                    // remove classes from all
                    $('li').removeClass('active');
                    // add class to the one we clicked
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                 });
              });
            </script>
```

But when i click on a list item, temporarily active class is getting set on the navigation item, but the page is getting refreshed and showing the current clicked list item without active class.

i have followed the instructions mentioned in [Toggle active class in nav bar with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459581/toggle-active-class-in-nav-bar-with-jquery)
with no success.

Could someone point out what i am missing.

Thanks

Comment: When you refresh the page, it will be reset to it's default state, which from the looks of things, has none set as active. To do what you are wanting, without the use of a server-side language, you'd need to set a cookie, with the value of the clicked `LI`.

Comment: What @crush said.  The effects you apply using javascript will not be inherited when the page refreshes.

Comment: you can add a class to active link using css (a:active )and then using jquery add active class to the closest li to that link.

Comment: @ssilas777 Could you please show me in an example. Sorry to ask, i am just new to web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This script runs after redirection happens, so this should work for you. We are adding a dummy class 'activeLink' to the active link and select the list based on that active link.*

```
 $(function(){
        $('ul li a').removeClass('activeLink');
        var url = window.location.pathname, 
            // create regexp to match current url pathname also to match the home link
            urlRegExp = new RegExp(url == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?$' : url.replace(/\/$/,'')); 
            // now grab every link from the navigation
            $('.ul li a').each(function(){
                // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
                if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
                    $(this).addClass('activeLink');
                }
            });

           $('li').removeClass('active');
           $('a.activeLink').closest('li').addClass('active');
    })
```

;