# How to write js or css for deleting class and writing class when you click another

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<nav class="mynav">
    <ul id="mynavigation">
        <li><a class="active" href="#hm">Main</a></li> /* Active Class */
        <li><a href="#pj">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#port">Port</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How to write css or js for....

If you click projects (tag a) then code should be working like this

```
<nav class="mynav">
    <ul id="mynavigation">
        <li><a class="" href="#hm">Main</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#pj">Projects</a></li>  /* Active Class */
        <li><a href="#port">Port</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Step
1.delete class='active' in id='mynavigation'
2.put class='active' in tag a that someone click in id='mynavigation'

Comment: Use jQuery to do this easily.

Comment: This topic is duplicated. You can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6459581/1177566

Comment: show us something you have tried and that didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle active class in nav bar with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459581/toggle-active-class-in-nav-bar-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's removeClass and addClass methods

```
$('#mynavigation li a').click(function(){
  $('#mynavigation li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

give the list items ID's and then just do

```
document.getElementById("myId").class = "";
```

And to activate it

```
document.getElementById("myId").class = "active";
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will work if your page is not reloading or redirecting to another

```
 $('body').on('click' , '#mynavigation li a', function(){
    $('#mynavigation li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active')
  });
```

if your code is going to somewhere else page then this script will not work.
To do the required thing you have to store the click link into the cache and then put the active class on the link which is stored in the cache

```
     var prevLink = '';

    if (checkCookie('clickedLink') != '') {
        prevLink = getCookie('clickedLink');
        $('.navi li a').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('href') == prevLink) {
                console.log($(this).attr('href'));
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
        })
    };

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    };

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    };

    function checkCookie(cookieName) {
        var user = getCookie(cookieName);
        if (user != "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

> $('#mynavigation').find('a').each(function(){
>   $(this).on('click',function(){ If(!($(this).hasClass('active'))){
>   $(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('active');
>   $(this).addClass('active');   } }); });